# Is android leeking memory or something wrong in my test code

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have an empty activity. this activity has a simple hello world. Created using New|Android application in eclipse.
What I observe is that if I dump the dalvik private memory of this application, everytime the activity is reloaded (orientation change) I see a rise in dalvik private memory for this process. Below is the log. Is this the right observation ? Please let me know

```
06-06 15:38:38.139: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM1956
06-06 15:38:41.599: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2120
06-06 15:38:43.989: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2240
06-06 15:38:45.959: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2364
06-06 15:38:47.769: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2488
06-06 15:38:49.999: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2612
06-06 15:38:51.989: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2736
06-06 15:38:54.019: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2852
06-06 15:38:55.789: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM2976
06-06 15:38:57.779: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM3088
06-06 15:39:04.389: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM3236
06-06 15:39:09.389: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM3364
06-06 15:39:10.389: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM3484
06-06 15:39:11.789: D/hworld(5477): DalvikPM3604
```

Code

```
package com.ahw.android_hello_world;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected Iterator i;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
         List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list= manager.getRunningAppProcesses();

     for(i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
        {
            RunningAppProcessInfo p = (RunningAppProcessInfo)i.next();
            if(p.processName.compareTo("com.ahw.android_hello_world")==0){

                int[] pids = new int[1];
                pids[0] = p.pid;
                ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

                android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] MI = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);

                Log.d("hworld","DalvikPM" + MI[0].dalvikPrivateDirty);
                break;

            }
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Update:::: 
Got a bit curious and looked at Advanced Task Manager my apps memory usage and it is shocking 6.8MB and it reached to 8mb and more by just changing the orientation.
What on earth is a hello world take 8mb for ? On a mobile device ?

Comment: Each app has a certain amount of memory it can use on it's own. Java / Android garbage collection has basically no need to clean up if there is still enough space so the used memory can grow each time you recreate your Activity.

Comment: is it. But then this would lead to internal fragmentation. If there are 10 processes in the system which havent consumed their quota and the gc is not invoked, so a new process has to starve or kick off one processes which may not be required if this internal fragmentation is taken care of...

Answer (score 0):

If you change the orientation of your device the activity is reloaded again so it calls to **onCreate** method. The other precesses didnt be released so every time that onCreate is called, a new process is executed and this do that the memory increase.

Comment: yes. but why should the overall memory of the process increase ?

Comment: Because the other processes are not released and you are looking your activity process.

Comment: did you understand what I mean?

Comment: no tato469. But I happen to press the home button launch diff apps and then come back to my app. Memory is always increasing...

Comment: Because the process doesnt finish with home button, it still in background.

Comment: so when will the process be released ? my whole point is very simple a hello world should not take mbs of memory. I dont know how to solve this riddle to use the least memory which should be < 1mb.